# How do I find the absolute path of my ini file from the directory i am calling my python script irrespective of the calling location?

Tags: python-3.x, absolute-path

The folder structure of my project is as follows

```
-ExpenseManager
    config.ini
    Icon.png
    __init__.py
    +bin
    -expenseManager
        main.py
        charting.py
        gui.py
        fileHandling.py
```

This project is in this path /home/sudeshna/Desktop/ExpenseManager.
main.py has the executable permission and I can run the program when I call the function from that directory (inside ../ExpenseManager/expenseManager/).

However , when I am trying to call the function from the base directory [/] I am getting a NoSectionError. 
I found out the reason behind it , as my main.py tries reading the config.ini file for some information .
The code for reading this is :-

```
    d = Path.dirname(Path.dirname(Path.abspath("__file__")))
    my_file = (os.path.join(d,'config.ini'))
    parser = SafeConfigParser()
    parser.read(my_file)
    folder_path = parser.get('folder_structure','path')
```

I have been trying to find a way such that the program reads the absolute path for config.ini irrespective of the place from where this script is called.
Till now I have used

```
    from pathlib import Path
    p = Path("../ExpenseManager/config.ini").resolve()
```

But it does not even find the ExpenseManager folder from the base directory [/] .

I tried to change these lines

```
    d = Path.dirname(Path.dirname(Path.abspath("__file__")))
    my_file = (os.path.join(d,'config.ini'))
```

to

```
   my_file = os.path.abspath('ExpenseManager/config.ini')
```

The problem I am facing now is my_file becomes

/home/sudeshna/Desktop/ExpenseManager/expenseManager/ExpenseManager/config.ini

instead of

/home/sudeshna/Desktop/ExpenseManager/config.ini

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the problem . But I don't actually understand what was causing the problem . I improved the code in the following line,

```
   d = Path.dirname(Path.dirname(Path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Keeping everything else same, I removed the "" surrounding the global variable

```
     __file__
```

The thing I am confused now is

```
  if "__file__" was not working ,
```

how was that above code segment was working from directory which contained the main.py code i.e. (../ExpenseManager/expenseManager) .

Any further explanation is always welcome. 
Please guide me if I am doing some conceptual mistakes.